# Cannot connect a slider control to GridLabels using HelixToolkit

Tags: wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I am trying to use GridLabels to display time in a model:

```
GridLabels.Add(new BillboardTextItem
{
    Text = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", "Time = ", 
    Well.TubeAnimTime.ToString("N0"), "Sec"),
    Position = new Point3D(0, 0, 500),
    WorldDepthOffset = 100
});
```

I tried to test this functionality using a Slider Control:

```
   <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Animation" />
        <Slider x:Name="AnimationSlider" Value="{Binding Well.TubeAnimTime}" 
        ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=AnimationSlider, Path=Value}" 
        Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
   </StackPanel>
```

Although the label displays OK and responds to all movements and zooming, it does not respond to the Slider. I know Slider works ok because other elements in my model  responds to it.
I tried to change the biding mode to TwoWay in:

```
<h:BillboardTextGroupVisual3D Background="Gray" Foreground="White" 
   FontSize="12" Offset="2,2"
   Padding="1" Items="{Binding GridLabels, Mode=OneWay, 
   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
   IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=FreezeAxisLblsCheckBox}"  />
```

VS 2017 does not allow me as the property seems to be readonly.

I really like Helix Toolkit but I seem to be slow learner. Anyone can explain why the binding with the Slider does not work. Or is there any easier way to display the time parameter in a distinct box like GridLabels?

I.Konuk

Answer (score 0):

Neither BillboardTextItem nor BillboardTextGroupVisual3D.Items is Observable. So the binding will not work.